# Why use Mongodb instead of MySql

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel, yii

I want to know that why use Mongodb over MySql. Anyone who have experience in Mongodb or on MySQl please suggest me.

Comment: If you not have any need for mongo, as you dont have since you ask why you should use it - then why even worry about it?

Comment: http://www.mongodb-is-web-scale.com/

Comment: It's better if you put your use case here, then ask. If you are just exploring better _google it_.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide if you need the "transactional" capabilities or SQL or the document (or object orient) data store functionality of MongoDB.  It is really a very lengthy and subjective discussion, not really best suited for here.

Comment: Surely someone must have thought of it (relational vs mongodb). Is it really that hard to post a link?